# Why am I getting CORS Error even after enabling Proxy setting in VueJs while making POST request to mapmyindia apis endpoints?

Tags: vue.js, post, proxy, axios

##### Error ScreenShot

[image]

##### Post Request Code (Vuejs)

```
let PROXY = "http://localhost:8080/";
let URL = PROXY + "api/security/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials"

URL += `&client_id=${this.ID}`;
URL += `&client_secret=${this.SECRET}`;

try {
  let res = await axios.post(URL, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }); 

  console.log(res);
}

catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

##### Vue.config.js (Proxy Setting)

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
        'https://outpost.mapmyindia.com/': {
          target: "http://localhost:8080/",
          changeOrigin: true
        }
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
}
```

I was getting a CORS-related error initially so I used this proxy thing but even then I am getting this error. There are some questions posted on StackOverflow related to the proxy setting in vuejs to remove CORS errors but none of them could resolve this issue therefore I have posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CORS issue. The ressource hasn't been found. You have 404 status code.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Through PostMan I am getting the response.